# Ebean, how to query result from table Customer_Product but order by product.category in table Product

Tags: ebean

can any one help me?
Here I have a table called PRODUCTS, it has PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, PRODUCT_NAME
and another table CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS, IT has CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID
How can I query CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS by a specific CUSTOMER_ID to get its products' PRODUCT_ID, and order by these products' PRODUCT_CATEGORY?

Any reply are helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Ebean.find(CUSTOMER_PRODUCTS.class)
.fetch("PRODUCTS")
.where()
.eq("CUSTOMER_ID",id)
.order("PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATEGORY");
```